# How to split markdown cell content into multiple cells in Jupiter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSU7o.png) Is there any way to simply insert code cell after each sentence in markdown(as i have copy pasted some paragraphs in markdown) instead of doing it manually pasting each sentence in cell.

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode of the cell, ctrl+shift+ - is working fine.